# Erro: Starting container process caused "exec: \"/docker-entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"

Tags: docker

Estou recebendo um erro na hora de dar o build no docker-compose:

```
ERROR: for indicaaquicombrold_mysqld_1  Cannot start service mysqld: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/docker-entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"


ERROR: for mysqld  Cannot start service mysqld: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/docker-entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    image: indicaaqui.com.br:tag
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
      - ./config/apache-config.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  mysqld: 
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_indicaaqui
      - MYSQL_USER=indicaqui
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker      
    volumes:
      - ./config/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.sh
      - ./database/db_indicaaqui.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_indicaaqui.sql
```

Dockerfile (php)

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

MAINTAINER Limup <limup@outlook.com>

CMD [ "php" ]

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Enable apache mods.
# RUN a2enmod php5.6
RUN a2enmod rewrite


# Expose apache. 
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Use the default production configuration
# RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

# Override with custom opcache settings
# COPY ./../../config/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/

# Manually set up the apache environment variables
 ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
 ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
 ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
 ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
 ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

# Update the PHP.ini file, enable <? ?> tags and quieten logging.
RUN sed -i "s/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*$/error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE/" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf 
RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# By default start up apache in the foreground, override with /bin/bash for interative.
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Dockerfile (Mysql)

```
FROM mariadb:latest

RUN chmod -R 777 /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Ajude-me a resolver este problema! Por favor.
Alguma idéia?

Comment: Consegui resolver! Dei permissão chmod 755 para o arquivo /docker-entrypoint.sh.

Mas agora obtive um novo erro: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

O erro `permission denied` provavelmente significa que seu arquivo `docker-entrypoint.sh` está sem permissões de leitura e/ou execução.

As três permissões básicas para arquivos são:

- (**R**) Leitura: Garante permissão para ler o conteúdo de um arquivo
- (**W**) Escrita: Permite a alteração do conteúdo de um arquivo
- (**X**) Execução: Permite a execução de um arquivo, se estes forem programas (arquivos que não são programas idealmente não devem ter permissões de execução)

Verfique as permissões do seu `docker-entrypoint.sh` e garanta as permissões de leitura e execução:

```
$ ls -l docker-entrypoint.sh 
-r-xr-xr-x 1 user user 25 set 17 10:33 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Utilize o `chmod` para [ajustar as permissões](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Como-dar-Permissao-de-Execucao-a-Arquivo-script-ou-binario-no-GNULinux-Abordagem-Pratica) conforme necessário:

- `chmod +r docker-entrypoint.sh` para permissões de leitura
- `chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh` para permissões de execução